# listing post keys to make it easier to use

Tags: php

I have 12 keys inside my `$_post[]`.

I can reach them without any issue but I want to make it easier, as there will be more keys (I am thinking of 30+).

Here is an example of what I have inside my $_post:

```
$_post['var1']
$_post['qty1']
$_post['var2']
$_post['qty2']
$_post['var3']
$_post['qty3']
```

This continues till 12 (at the moment).

It is being posted this way:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($results as $mat) {
    $count++;
    echo "<tr><td>{$count}</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='var{$count}' value='{$mat['var']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='qty{$count}' value='{$mat['qty']}' /></td></tr>";
}
```

I need to use those variables later to update my sql table, and to have it done one-by-one is a nightmare ( as I am still not sure how many it will be ).

What can I do to achieve it in an easier way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make name as array like this. `var[]` and `qty[]`

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='var[]' value='{$mat['var']}' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='qty[]' value='{$mat['qty']}' /></td></tr>";
```

and receive in php like this

```
$arr_var = $_POST['var'];
$arr_qty = $_POST['qty'];

foreach($arr_var as $key=>$value)
{ 
   $var = $value;
   $qty = $arr_qty[$key];
}
```

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was looking for but thanks to your hint I fixed it;)


$arr_var = $_POST['var'];
$arr_qty = $_POST['qty'];
$total = $numKeys = count($arr_var);
$count = 0;
while($count < $total){
$sql3="UPDATE table1 set qty = qty - {$arr_qty[$count]} WHERE  var='{$arr_var[$count]}'";
    $count++;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{ 
   $$key = $value; // notice the $$, it's known as variable variable
   // remove the below comment if you want to see how they are coming out
   // echo "$".$key." = ". $value."<br />";
}
```

This will create variables names based on the `name` attribute of the input box.

Comment: This is risky though: what if one of the keys is `_POST`? It can overwrite things you do not intend to overwrite.